# some issue in this linq to xml query, while getting value of certain attribute in an element

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have this app.config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="domain" value="localhost"/>

    <add key="hostname" value="hostpc"/>

 </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

I am using this LINQ to XML query to get the value of key named "domain". For instance, when i say i want to get value of key named "domain" it should give me "localhost" :

```
var domain = (from appNode in xmlElement.Elements("add")
                     where appNode.Attribute("key").Value == "domain"
                     select appNode.Attribute("value"));
```

But my query is missing something can anyone identify what i am missing or how it can be made better, it doesn't work at the moment.

Note: I only want to use linq to xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your app.config file content as it is, write a small console based application with following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create the query 
        var nodes = from appNode in XElement.Load("App.config").Descendants("appSettings").Elements()
                    where appNode.Attribute("key").Value == "domain"
                    select appNode;

        var element = nodes.FirstOrDefault();
        string value = element.Attribute("value").Value;

        Console.WriteLine(value);

        //Pause the application 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output is: localhost

Hope this helps. If it does not work on your machine, please share error details.

Comment: i am debugging and the value returned by this for domain is  domain {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>} System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement> {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>}

Comment: The comment is not helping, try the code I shared in my answer. If the code does not work, share the exception details you get. Please update the question to include more details like what is the exception, at what point you are getting the exception, etc. It will help us helping you :)

Answer (score 0):

try using this one:

```
    XElement doc = XElement.Load("ConsoleApplication1.exe.config");

    var domain = (from appNode in doc.Element("appSettings").Elements("add")
                  where appNode.Attribute("key").Value == "domain"
                  select appNode.Attribute("value").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```